# Are there benefits to using mineral water in your mash?

Tags: mash, water, distillation

Should you use boiled tap water or mineral water when making spirit?

Comment: Some information about mineral water:: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/any-special-considerations-besides-taste-when-brewing-with-mineral-water

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making spirits, the goal is usually to create a quick and clean fermentation of mash. If the tap water in your area would prevent the fermentation from being clean or fast, then a mineral or spring water would be fine. I see no problem in using either water if both are good for yeast.